# How i can draw more than 1 polygon. Google api

Tags: api, google-maps-api-3, polygon

i have several array of coords, and i need draw more than 1 polygon

```
function testarr() 
{
        polygon1 = [new google.maps.LatLng(54.66092513983568, 39.71935272216797),
        new google.maps.LatLng(54.63847909506459, 39.718666076660156),
        new google.maps.LatLng(54.63748562083948, 39.77668762207031),
        new google.maps.LatLng(54.66430090574764, 39.77668762207031)];

        polygon2 = [new google.maps.LatLng(54.605482774276126, 39.713172912597656),
        new google.maps.LatLng(54.58817883247707, 39.714202880859375),
        new google.maps.LatLng(54.58917351104145, 39.734458923339844),
        new google.maps.LatLng(54.607073572207575, 39.7320556640625)];

        polygonpolygon.push(polygon1);
        polygonpolygon.push(polygon2);
}
```

how create new polygon with new coordinates, if i don't know how many polygons i need?

i try this, but it`s wrong :

```
var polyg = new google.maps.Polygon({
        fillColor: 'blue',
        path: polyarr111,
        strokeWeight: 3
        });

    for (var u=0; u<2; u++) { 
        polyg.setPaths(new google.maps.MVCArray(polygonpolygon[u]));
    };
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You pushed your paths to an array `polygonpolygon` so you can loop through it to create your polygons.

```
var polygonOptions = {
    fillColor: 'blue',
    strokeWeight: 3
};

for (var u=0; u<polygonpolygon.length; u++) {
    var polygon = new google.maps.Polygon(polygonOptions);
    polygon.setPaths(polygonpolygon[u]);
    polygon.setMap(map);
};
```

This way it will create any number of polygons that are in your array.

<kbd>[Working demo](http://jsfiddle.net/upsidown/C7mqS/)</kbd>